# Customer group not changed from "NOT LOGGED IN" during checkout registration!

Tags: checkout

We have a reward points extension installed, with a rule to reward when a customer signs up and also points for their purcahse.  It doesn't work correctly when a customer registers during checkout.  The customer group is not changing from "NOT LOGGED IN" it seems.  Is this what happens as standard in Magento, as I need the customer group to change to the default group it is eventually given (after they have made their purchase)??  This issue has held us back from going live! :/

Thanks,

Manny

Answer (score 1):

It depends whether a new customer account has just been created, or if the customer has actually been logged into that account as well.  If they have been logged in then the group will no longer be not logged in, so it sounds like they haven't been logged in in this case.  During the normal checkout flow if you register you do end up logged in if you register a new account so if you are using the standard checkout flow check at which point you are looking at the user group and make sure the user has been logged in by then.

Comment: Thanks for responding.  So in the normal checkout flow, you should get logged in if you register an account during the checkout process?  And not be in the "NOT LOGGED IN" group at that time?

Comment: By the time you reach the checkout success page I believe you should find yourself logged in if you weren't before yes.